# Why is this negative look behind wrong?

Tags: ruby, regex, negative-lookbehind

```
def get_hashtags(post)
    tags = []
    post.scan(/(?<![0-9a-zA-Z])(#+)([a-zA-Z]+)/){|x,y| tags << y}
    tags
end
```

---

```
Test.assert_equals(get_hashtags("two hashs##in middle of word#"), [])
#Expected: [], instead got: ["in"]
```

Should it not look behind to see if the match doesnt begin with a word or number? Why is it still accepting 'in' as a valid match?

Comment: Because the pattern succeeds on the second # (that is not preceded by `[0-9a-zA-Z]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\K` rather than a negative lookbehind. That allows you  to simplify your regex considerably: no need for a pre-defined array, capture groups or a block.

`\K` means "discard everything matched so far". The key here is that variable-length matches can precede `\K`, whereas (in Ruby and most other languages) variable-length matches are not permitted in (negative or positive) lookbehinds.

```
r = /
    [^0-9a-zA-Z#] # do not match any character in the character class
    \#+           # match one or more pound signs
    \K            # discard everything matched so far
    [a-zA-Z]+     # match one or more letters
    /x            # extended mode
```

Note `#` in `\#+` need not be escaped if I weren't writing the regex in extended mode.

```
"two hashs##in middle of word#".scan r
  #=> []

"two hashs&#in middle of word#".scan r
  #=> ["in"]

"two hashs#in middle of word&#abc of another word.###def ".scan r
   #=> ["abc", "def"]
```

Comment: I had been looking for this solution for so long now. Thanks, mate.